# Homodyne detection for arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

In your code https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/0b03735d70366bc05fc6 for homodyne detection, is there a way to make the frequency detected a range of frequencies? For example detecting between 3kHz and 4kHz?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to modify that program in order to get such a large
frequency range:

- change the local oscillator frequency to 3.5 kHz
- drastically shorten the filter's time constant in order to get a
  wider passband

However, the homodyne detection scheme is best suited for building very
narrow band filters. In your case, the upper limit you want is quite
close to the Nyquist frequency (4,808 Hz), so I suggest you use a
high-pass, rather than a band-pass filter. The simplest high-pass you
can get is a numerical derivative:

y[n] = x[n] − x[n−1]

The gain of this filter is 2×sin(π×f/f<sub>samp</sub>), so you get the
−3 dB cutoff at f<sub>samp</sub>/4 ≈ 2,404 Hz. If you need
something better, you may want to try a higher order filter. But then
you get deep into the territory of digital filter design, which can be
tricky, especially if you have no experience with the z-transform or you
want to implement the filter in fixed point.

**Edit**: If you really want a bandpass, the simplest I can think of is
this two-pole filter:

y[n] = 0.360 x[n] − 0.885 y[n−1] − 0.552 y[n−2]

It will give you a maximum gain of roughly 1 at about
3.43 kHz, and −3 dB cutoffs at 3 and 4 kHz. A
straightforward floating point implementation would be:

```cpp
float filter(float x)
{
    static float y1, y2;
    float y = 0.360 * x - 0.885 * y1 - 0.552 * y2;
    y2 = y1;
    y1 = y;
    return y;
}
```

You should convert this to fixed point if you want to use it, otherwise
I doubt your Arduino will have the processing power to run every sample
through it. Below is a plot of this filter's gain, compared with the
simple derivative, which I divided by 2 in order to normalize its
gain:

[image: gain vs frequency]

Note that the gain gets flat as you approach the Nyquist frequency, and
stays relatively high (above −5.4 dB).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you maybe show a code that already has that bandpass implemented in your previous code. We are not really experienced with Arduino so we really cannot figure out what exactly to change in your code... Thank you so much for your answers already though!